# WKWebView subclass crashes on dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, wkwebview

When my `WKWebView` subclass (`MyWKWebView`) `dealloc`s, it crashes thusly:

> 2016-05-05 15:40:08.814 MyApp[15559:202920] -[MyViewController
>   dealloc]: In MyViewController dealloc objc[15559]: Cannot form weak
>   reference to instance (0x7f9db7f0dbf0) of class MyWKWebView. It is
>   possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of
>   deallocation.

I have no weak references to the `MyWKWebView`, but the `MyWKWebView` itself holds a weak reference to my `UIViewController` subclass (`MyViewController`), which owns `MyWKWebView`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An apparently important detail I didn't realize: my `WKWebView` subclass (`MyWKWebView`) conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. (I'm trying to make `WKWebView` API-compatible with `UIWebView` so I can easily swap them between iOS7 and later versions.)

This matters because `WKWebView` already conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, though it doesn't say so in [the header](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.h):

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
WK_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0)
@interface WKWebView : UIView
#else
```

However, if you look in the [WKWebViewInternal.h header](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebViewInternal.h), we see a suspicious category:

```
@interface WKWebView () WK_WEB_VIEW_PROTOCOLS
```

and if we look further up in the file, we see that `WK_WEB_VIEW_PROTOCOLS` is `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` on iOS:

```
#if PLATFORM(IOS)
#define WK_WEB_VIEW_PROTOCOLS <UIScrollViewDelegate>
#endif
```

I can't find anywhere that would explicitly cause an overrelease, but I'm surely screwing up something in `WKWebView` by not allowing its proper `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to be called.

The workaround is to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` in a separate object.